# Java loop not parsing second int

Tags: java, for-loop, parseint

My assignment is to write a program that will take a string, such as C2O3M1P1R1E1S10,
and decompress it into CCOOOMPRESSSSSSSSSS. I can't get the program to correctly parse a 2 digit number though. Here is what I have. I know i'm close.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();
int index = 0;
int numReps = 0;
char nextChar = ' ';

while (index < input.length())
{

  char c = input.charAt(index);

  if (!Character.isDigit(c))
  {
    nextChar = c;
    index++;
  }

  else
  {

    while (Character.isDigit(c))
    {
      int temp = Integer.parseInt(""+c);
      numReps = (numReps*10)+temp;
      index++;
      System.out.print(nextChar);

      if (index >= input.length()) break;
       c = input.charAt(index);
    }

  }
}
```

This is actually only one part of a larger program so if some of the formatting is off I apologize.

Comment: numReps is initialized outside of your loop. It looks to me like it will work for the first number, but you need to set it back to zero before you start parsing a second sequence of digits.

Comment: Seems like numReps is important, but after you assign value to it you never use it. Same with temp.

Comment: I suggest you step back from the code and write **in words** the steps you need to take to solve the initial problem. I believe that when you do this, you will see some of the problems with your current code. If you still have trouble, you will have a much better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your code sample doesn't really make much sense. As the others said, you _calculate_ `temp` and `numReps` but don't use them. You print out `nextChar` even though it might be blank. I think you need a do over. Start by explaining what you're trying to achieve _much_ more clearly - step by step

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop you need to convert digits to `number` and after that loop letter create another one and iterate `number` times printing `nextChar`.

Now you are just printing `nextChar` each time you read digit from string.

To make things easier you can store each digit you read in `StringBuilder` and then parse it to integer with `Integer.parseInt(yourStringBuilder.toString())`.